# Browser Back Button in vue-router doesn't do anything

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is the vue router in hash mode supposed to react when you hit the back button in the browser?

I’m using the most current package, and I’ve searched and searched and I have seen this bug reported elsewhere, but I’ve never seen it resolved. If this is working as intended then I don’t need to try to debug my code

Thanks for any help

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure it should react, but it might not do anything if you re-use the same component.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - We ended up just switching to history mode.

According to this git commit though, updating to vue-router@3.4.9 should fix it
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/commit/a95795c1c59361ab7cc23009ff2e2aecd46827a1

I haven't tested this but I thought I would leave what solution I found